# For loop adding notes to a midi file, toneJS

Tags: node.js, express, midi

I'm creating a midi file based on frequencies.
I'm using ToneJS (in Node.js) to create the midi file with this code:

```
exports.createMidiFile = (req,res,next) => {
  // create a new midi file
var midi = new Midi()
// add a track
const track = midi.addTrack()
track.addNote({
  midi : Tone.Frequency(400).toMidi(),
  time : 0,
  duration: 10
})

// write the output
fs.writeFileSync("output.mid", new Buffer(midi.toArray()))
}
```

What im trying to do is a for loop to add notes to the same track.
I tried:

```
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){
track.addNote({
  midi : Tone.Frequency(i).toMidi(),
  time : 0,
  duration: 10
})
}
```

But when i try to open the file it says the file is damaged..

Thanks in advance friends.

Comment: What library are you using ? As far as I know, `new Midi()` is not native JavaScript

Comment: @KiJéy I wrote at the beginning  " I'm using ToneJS ".

Comment: I see in the documentation that the calls to `addNode()` ar chained. Try with `track = track.addNote()`

Comment: i want to chain addNote() , so beside writing ```track.addNote().addNote().addNote()``` i want to have for loop to do it without adding it manualy

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your loop like this :

```js
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){
  track = track.addNote({
    midi : Tone.Frequency(i).toMidi(),
    time : 0,
    duration: 10
  })
}
```

Doing this makes it equivalent to chaining the calls to `addNote()`

Comment: ok i will give it a try and i will check if its working, thank you for answering.

Comment: its not working :/ . i need to chain the addNote somehow...